# EaselJs: Objects, Classes, and Making A Square Move

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs, createjs

Although I have used Javascript extensively in the past, I have never used classes and objects in my programs. This is also the first for me using the HTML5 `canvas` element with an extra Javascript library. The library I'm using is EaselJS.

Short and sweet, I'm trying to make a square move with keyboard input, using object-oriented programming. I've already looked over [sample game files](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/examples/Game.html), but I've never been able to properly get one to work.

The following is my classes script:

```
/*global createjs*/

// Shorthand createjs.Shape Variable
var Shape = createjs.Shape;

// Main Square Class
function square(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.vX = 0;
    this.vY = 0;
    this.canMove = false;

    this.vX = this.vY = 0;
    this.canMove = false;

    this.body = new Shape();
    this.body.graphics.beginFill("#ff0000").drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
}
```

And below is my main script:

```
/*global createjs, document, window, square, alert*/

// Canvas and Stage Variables
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var stage = new createjs.Stage("c");


// Shorthand Create.js Variables
var Ticker = createjs.Ticker;


// Important Keycodes
var keycode_w = 87;
var keycode_a = 65;
var keycode_s = 83;
var keycode_d = 68;

var keycode_left = 37;
var keycode_right = 39;
var keycode_up = 38;
var keycode_down = 40;

var keycode_space = 32;


// Handle Key Down
window.onkeydown = handleKeyDown;
var lfHeld = false;
var rtHeld = false;


// Create Protagonist
var protagonist = new square("Mr. Blue");


// Set Up Ticker
Ticker.setFPS(60);
Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
if (!Ticker.hasEventListener("tick")) { 
    Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);
}

// Init Function, Prepare Protagonist Placement
function init() {
    protagonist.x = c.width / 2;
    protagonist.y = c.height / 2;

    stage.addChild(protagonist);
}

// Ticker Test
function tick() {
    if (lfHeld) {
        alert("test");
    }
}

// Handle Key Down Function
function handleKeyDown(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
        case keycode_a:
        case keycode_left: lfHeld = true; return false;
        case keycode_d:
        case keycode_right: rtHeld = true; return false;
    }
}
```

This is the error I get in the Developer Tools of Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
easeljs-0.7.0.min.js:13
```

In case you're wondering, the order of my `script` tags is the EaselJS CDN, followed by my class, followed by the main script file.

I would really like closure on this question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot use your `square` class just like that, you need to extend from some createjs-class, like `DisplayObject` - take a look at this file and apply those methodologies to your `square`: https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/examples/assets/Ship.js

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was adding the entire `protagonist` instance to the stage. I've fixed by adding the protagonist.body to the stage.